# How do I get current emission intensity of a material in code?

Tags: unity, c#, rendering, materials

I'm unable to find how can I get current intensity level of emission in Unity.

Is there some kind of method that can return its value?

I need it to complete my algorithm's formula:

```
current_color = (intensity * 10)/20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "Intensity", here are a couple of options:

```
// This gives you the multiplier applied to the colour, 
// assuming the source colour had its greatest component set to 1
static float GetEmissionMultiplier(Material mat) {
    var colour = mat.GetColor("_EmissionColor");        
    return Mathf.Max(colour.r, colour.g, colour.b);
}

// This gives the perceived luminance of the emissive colour,
// accounting for the fact that green is brighter than blue,
// and yellow (red + green) is brighter than green, etc.
// Coefficients via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)
static float GetEmissionLuminance(Material mat) {
    var colour = mat.GetVector("_EmissionColor");        
    return Vector4.Dot(colour, new Vector4(0.2126f, 0.7152f, 0.0722f, 0.0f));
}
```